# Infinitely Counting Real Numbers

Tags: number-theory, infinity, real-numbers

I would like to show an idea on how to make real numbers infinitely countable. It is quite simple, too simple for me to believe it has been overlooked. So my question is, what have I overlooked?

[image]

So the "countable" list would start like this
{0.1, 0.2, 1.1, 2.1, 1.2, 0.3, 0.4, 1.3, 2.2, 3.1 ...}, the way Cantor diagonally counted the list of rational numbers and potentially covering every real number there is.

And for the numbers after the decimal point, you go down a column and count normally after the decimal point but reverse the number.

Comment: It is really funny coming back to this question after 6 years and realizing how naive I was. Oh well. Progress through failure and humiliation. https://xkcd.com/1053/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This construction only covers the real numbers that have a *finite* decimal representation. These numbers are all rational - but you don't even cover all rational numbers, since they may have a periodic decimal representation [e.g. $\frac{1}{3} = 0.\overline{3}$].

Comment: But wouldn't 0.3333... occure in the list. After the decimal point the numbers are counted to infinity so 0.333333333... would just be at the end of the list? –  Xajoc8 just now   edit   delete

Comment: No, there is no "end of the list". Exactly those numbers occur that have a finite place in the list.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your time and answer. There are clearly some things I haven't understood/heard of yet. Have a good day

Answer (score 1):

All the numbers in your list have finite decimal expansions, so they are rational. In particular, $\sqrt 2$ is not on your list.